# How can I discover optimal colours of contrast?

Tags: colors

Barring manual eyeballing, how can I pinpoint the ideal colour contrast to my selections?

http://www.talkgraphics.com/showthread.php?32121-How-to-find-a-contrasting-color and https://kuler.adobe.com/create/color-wheel/ bases its contrasts on only the first choice. I prefer a tool that continually updates its colour suggestions as I select more colours.

**Response to user 'karel':** My goal is to improve my colour choices when sketching diagrams or typing in multifarious colours ([for different math equations](http://www.math.harvard.edu/computing/latex/color.html)) for maximum contrast. So far, I've resorted to [Complementary colours](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Complementary_colors) but how should I pick the 3rd, 4th, ... colours?

For example, red and purple this [post](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/456203/visual-interpretation-of-cv-1-cw) are too similar, and fail to contrast the two vectors as independent and separate.

Comment: You might consider editing your answer, *not* asking for tools, since this could be an off topic close reason.

Comment: @bummi: Thank you very much! I've emended my OP.

Comment: @karel: Thank you for your answer. I added some more context. Does it help? Please let me know if you need more!

Comment: @LePressentiment I have tried generating the color choices programmatically using a Bash script. Please comment on my answer and suggest possible improvements, and I will try to change the Bash script to meet your requirements.

Comment: https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/q/352/121005 and https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/809/good-resources-for-colour-schemes?noredirect=1&lq=1 fit my search more. But I accepted the other answer to thank him.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have tried to generate a set of six colors selected for optimal contrast and readability using the following Bash script:

```
#!/bin/bash

for i in {1..6}
do
    tput setaf $i
    echo 'color ' $i ' ■■■■■■■■■■■■■■■■■■■■■'
done
```

The results of running the Bash script are shown below:

[image]

These results are quite good compared to the results of selecting colors for optimal contrast and readability manually using a color replacement tool.

Comment: It'd be preferable to include the script as text, not as an image only. `for i in $(seq …)` could be shortened to `for i in {1..6}`.

Comment: Thank you! +1. Excepting programming and scripts, are there any other ways to do this? I know very little about them.

Comment: The numeric values for an integer set of contrasting colors can also be derived from the numeric values of the colors (as are obtained using the eyedropper color picker tool in an image editor like GIMP or Photoshop). I believe that this is suboptimal however, because human beings do not perceive colors on a linear scale and dogs, for example, see green tones better than other tones because they are partially color blind. Any time you want to chat further about this topic, comment here and I'll create a private Stack Exchange gallery chat room for this purpose. :)

Comment: Thank you deeply again. I'd love to be able to +1 multiple times thus I'll upvote your other sterling answers. Please feel free to create a chat room, though I hope that I'm not expending too much of your time. Are there instructions or guides or videos as regards how to do this in GIMP or Photoshop? I'll be delighted to select this answer once I determine this.

Comment: The Color Picker Tool in GIMP Toolbox is used to select a color. Clicking on the Foreground/Background square color patches in GIMP Toolbox opens the Change Foreground Color window where the numerical value of the color you have selected with the Color Picker Tool is displayed.